# Adding click handler to geojson in maps API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there a way to associate a GeoJson with a click event?

```
  const features = map.data.addGeoJson(json);
  for (const feature of features) {
    // Add styling
    map.data.overrideStyle(
        feature,{
          fillColor: 'red',
        });
    // TODO: Add a click handler for "feature"
  }
```

For normal entities, such as [`LatLngBounds`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3/event#event.addListener), there seems to be `addListener(instance, eventName, handler)`. This does however not exist for the feature from the snippet above.

Is there an equivalent alternative for geojson features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I just found this [help page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer#add_event_handlers), which gives a snippet on how to do this:

```
// Set mouseover event for each feature.
map.data.addListener('mouseover', function(event) {
  // "event" has the feature as a property.
  document.getElementById('info-box').textContent =
      event.feature.getProperty('letter');
});
```